# Cómo discriminar las celdas insertar dentro de un row con una consulta LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

tengo un `dataGridView` formado de una columna de `checkBoxs` y otras dos de tipo texto, para recoger los `rows` en los que el `checkbox` está en `enable`, uso una consulta `LINQ` para meterlos en una `List<DataGridViewRow>`:

```
  List<DataGridViewRow> values = new List<DataGridViewRow>(
            from DataGridViewRow row in ewgrid1.Rows
            where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["colCheck"].Value) == true
            select row
            );
```

Esto funciona perfectamente, pero me gustaría recoger solo las columnas de tipo texto, es decir obviar la columna de `checkboxs`.
¿Me podéis echar una mano por favor?

Comment: Vos lo que queres es quedarte con el `string` directamente? o quedarte con un `DataGridViewRow` sola columna? No está muy clara la pregunta!

Comment: Disculpa si no me expresé bien. El `datagridview` está compuesto de 3 columnas:
' CheckBoxs' , string iD y string Nombre.
Lo que quiero es que la `List<DataGridViewRow>` solo recoja las columnas id y nombre, ya que la columna de `checkboxs`, ya no me sirve de nada.
Ya sé que puedo eliminarla a posteriori, pero era para hacer el código más limpio.

Answer (score 0):

En el select, en lugar de recuperar la fila completa, podes indicar las columnas que queres recuperar: select row[columnaTexto1], row[columnaTexto2]

Comment: Eso no me ha funcionado, pero muchas gracias.